# how to SOAP with PHP to a SAP Erecruitment database

Tags: php, soap, sap

Our team is working on SAP and getting a website frontend written with PHP and MySQL to connect with the recruitment database on SAP ...
we've tried making SOAP clients and everything but it seems we're missing something.. what are the steps to ensure that they can synchronize with or without a wsdl..

Answer (score 1):

The standard PHP SOAP module has always worked for me.... http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.soap-soapclient-construct.php

Answer (score 0):

it might make more sense to use RFC's instead, that way

- List item
- No marshalling and unmarshalling
- You can use standard delivered and supported SAP code
- You dont need to create web services for function modules or groups

  Link for the adapter : http://saprfc.sourceforge.net/home.php

  Link for buying the book : http://www.sap-press.com/product.cfm?account=&product=H1908